# Scope Variable calling http service stays undefined

Tags: angularjs, http

This might be a beginner question, but why does the $scope.usercountry Variable stays undefinded, although the service is successful?

http://jsfiddle.net/9twyLna1/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myService', function ($http) {
return {

    userCountry: function () {
        $http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json").success(function (data) {
            var userCountry = data.country;
            alert(userCountry);
            return userCountry;
        });

    }

  };

});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
$scope.usercountry = myService.userCountry();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http works in asynch way, what it means is when you call a service **userCountry**, an asynch call to the end point will be made and code will come back to the calling function. So basically you are trying to show the data before it is actually fetched. This is the basic behaviour when you work with promises.

To overcome this you will need to return a promise from the service and from calling function you should wait until data comes back from http request.

you can read about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).
updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9twyLna1/3/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    return {

        userCountry: function () {
            return $http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json");
        }

    };

});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.usercountry = myService.userCountry().then(function(data){
      return data.data.country;        
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! And if I want to call the $http request only once and then store the value for the whole app? So that I dont call the ipinfo service again and again? (After 1000 requests I would have to pay otherwise...)